# Resizable Text jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want the text to be restored proportionally when pulled left and right.It just resizes the outside div, but doesn't make the text bigger or smaller

```js
function getContentDiagonal() {
  var contentWidth = $("#deneme").width();
  var contentHeight = $("#deneme").height();
  return contentWidth * contentWidth + contentHeight * contentHeight;
}

$(function() {

  $("#deneme").resizable({

    create: function(event, ui) {
      initDiagonal = getContentDiagonal();
      initFontSize = parseInt($("#resizable").css("font-size"));
    },

    resize: function(e, ui) {
      var newDiagonal = getContentDiagonal();
      var ratio = newDiagonal / initDiagonal;
      $("#deneme").css("font-size", initFontSize + ratio * 3);
    }


  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for providing the JS part. Can you please also create a [mcve]? It's obviously hard to see what's going on by just looking at JS.

Comment: I want to resize the text by pulling it to the right. Do you have an example of this? @RokoC.Buljan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have one typo in your script, instead of:

```
initFontSize = parseInt($("#resizable").css("font-size"));
```

there should be:

```
initFontSize = parseInt($("#deneme").css("font-size"));
```

You can see it working just fine on [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skobaljic/9c5zgkeh/5/).

Comment: It's not proportional. And it even wraps. But yeah, great catch

Comment: I haven't changed his equation to maintain proportionality, no doubt he can adjust it.